# How to Establish cross org connections in VF page

Tags: visualforce, callout

UPDATED::
The page redirection is going to a login page, even after I got the access token. Any idea how I can redirect, as the session is established already?

Controller

```
public with sharing class CPQPunchout3{


       public CPQPunchout3()
    {

    }

    public PageReference fetch()
    {

        String endpoint='https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token';
      //String endpoint = 'https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=&redirect_uri=&scope=visualforce';

//Pass the credentials using usrnm passwrd flow

String username = 'xxxxxx'; 
String password = 'xxxxxxx';
String ClientId= 'xxxxxx';
String ClientSecret = 'xxxxxxx'; 

Httprequest req = new HttpRequest();    
req.setMethod('POST');    
req.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

req.setBody('grant_type=password' + 
      '&client_id=' + ClientId + 
      '&client_secret=' + ClientSecret + 
      '&username=' + username +
      '&password=' + password
   );    
req.setEndpoint(endpoint);         
Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse res;       
String Access_Token;
try {
    res = http.send(req);                
    system.debug('body:'+res.getBody());  
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(res.getBody());
    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if ((parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME) && (parser.getText() == 'access_token')) {
                parser.nextToken();
                Access_Token = parser.getText(); 
              // Access_Token =  'https://XXXX.na78.visual.force.com/apex/vfpage?oauth_token='   ;
                } 
        }            
}catch(system.CalloutException e){            
    system.debug('error'+e);
}
 system.debug('access token'+Access_Token);
//Httprequest req1 = new HttpRequest();  
//req1.setEndpoint('https://XXXX.na78.visual.force.com/apex/vfpage?oauth_token=');  
//req1.setMethod('GET');    
//we can use any of two below lines for content Type.
//req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
//req1.setHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
//req1.setHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+Access_Token);            
//Http http1 = new Http();
//HttpResponse res1 = http1.send(req1);                 
//system.debug('body11:'+res1.getBody()); 
//return res1.getBody();
 PageReference pageRef = new PageReference('https://XXX.na78.visual.force.com/apex/VFPAGE');
  return pageRef;
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: you need to explore canvas app

Comment: Thanks @SantanuBoral. WIthout that app, is there no way to pass the credentials and access the vf page?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying access visualforce page that exists in other org without login into the other org (using SSO), then leverage Force.com Canvas App.

The Identity Provider will be your org which is initiating the request and hosting the Canvap app, probably in Visualforce page.

Service Provider will host that visualforce which you are trying to access from your org (IdP).

Here is the step by step implementation:

[Implementing SAML SSO for Canvas Apps](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Implementing_SAML_SSO_for_Canvas_Apps)

You should also refer this video:

[Seamless Authentication with Force.com Canvas](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCvgyXjnnsY)

Comment: :: Thanks a lot Sir. I will follow the instruction. COuld you kindly tell me what did you mean by "hosting the Canvap app, probably in Visualforce page."

Comment: It means Your org with create a Connected App which will be of type Force.com Canvas. refer that link, you will understand all

Comment: Thank you once again Sir. I shall try this and keep you posted. Appreciate your support @Santanu Boral

Comment: I cannot do this in a sandbox org, as it needs dev box. I wanted to do this in my sandbox. So I am not sure if this is helpful Sir

Comment: It's an example. You can absolutely use sandbox orgs for this.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor I edited the post with code. The page reference is still routing to login page

Comment: @SantanuBoral: Sir any thoughts on this code? I have updated the code above.

Comment: I have given the easiest and optimized approach, did you get a chance to look into the link and video?